# Why does Access to Modified Closure Warning Disappear When Enumerable Method called with ()

Tags: .net, linq, foreach, closures, resharper

Resharper's [`Access to Modified Closure`](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/Access+to+modified+closure) warnings are usually quite helpful. I was just noticing that when I call the [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) method inside of a for each loop, I'll get a warning if I don't use the open and close parenthesis. As soon as I add `()`, the error goes away.

Does the error itself go away, or have I just accidentally tricked Resharper's static code analysis detection.

```vb
Dim groupExists as Boolean

For each oldPerson in oldData

    'access to modified closure warning on oldPerson.groupId
    groupExists = (From newPerson In newData 
                   Where newPerson.GroupId = oldPerson.groupId).Any

    'no closure problem reported
    groupExists = (From newPerson In newData 
                   Where newPerson.GroupId = oldPerson.groupId).Any()

Next
```

Of course, I can fix this by putting the following code inside the `For Each` loop and comparing the `newPerson.GroupId` to the locally declared variable.

```vb
'declare locally to avoid access to modified closure
Dim groupId as Integer = person.groupId
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a Resharper bug and I'd submit it there. There can't be a modified closure in a linq statement that's executing immediately, like `Any` does.

VB is not my 'native language', but afaik the parentheses shouldn't make any difference in VB.Net (as it did in VB6).